# Check for cells containing strings with non-latin letter characters in Googlesheets using Regex with QUERY

Tags: regex, google-sheets, unicode, google-sheets-query, re2

I'm currently working with a database in Googlesheets containing app publishers linked to financial apps. I plan to match it with another list that has multiple bank names from multiple countries. The problem is that the first database has the names of the publishers as the original names, but second list has some bank names translated to English and some of them have the original native name. Specifically, the names of banks that appear to be written originally with a non-Latin script (such as Korean, Cyrillic, Japanese or Arabic) have been translated to English, and the names of banks that are written in a Latin-script-based language (as Spanish, Romanian, Slovenian or French) all appear to be not translated, just without any diacritic.

Because of this, i'm trying to use Regex in Googlesheets in order to check the cells for non-Latin Unicode **letter** characters (and that's why [this question doesn't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124010/grep-regex-to-match-non-ascii-characters), nor [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59720646/check-for-non-latin-characters-with-regexmatch-for-google-sheets)). Since currently Googlesheets' `REGEXMATCH` is incompatible with Unicode class characters, i've been forced to use the `QUERY` function (following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55933865)). Let's say that I have this column A:

```
A
融360
הבנק הבינלאומי
АТ "Акцент-Банк
АО АЛСЕКО
АО "Altyn Bank"
АКБ "Kapitalbank
Şekerbank
İninal
Československá obchodní banka
iBillionaire
iBear
iBankマーケティング株式会社
4finance
11번가(주)
11com7 design
1 2 3 Apps
1 2 3 Apps
(주)인포바인
```

I want to use `QUERY` in another column combined with `WHERE MATCHES` in order to be able to use the Latin Unicode class, and I want the `QUERY` function to give results only when non-Latin letter characters appear. That is, I want something like this as a result in column B:

```
A:B
融360:融360
הבנק הבינלאומי:הבנק הבינלאומי
АТ "Акцент-Банк:АТ "Акцент-Банк
АО АЛСЕКО:АО АЛСЕКО
АО "Altyn Bank":АО "Altyn Bank" \\ These are Cyrillic A and O
АКБ "Kapitalbank:АКБ "Kapitalbank
Şekerbank:#N/A
İninal:#N/A
Československá obchodní banka:#N/A
iBillionaire:#N/A
iBear:#N/A
iBankマーケティング株式会社:iBankマーケティング株式会社
4finance:#N/A
11번가(주):11번가(주)
11com7 design:#N/A
1 2 3 Apps:#N/A
1 2 3 Apps:#N/A
(주)인포바인:(주)인포바인
```

I'm doing this with this formula: `=QUERY(A;"select A where A matches 'SomeREGEX'";0)`, but I don't seem to get the correct regular expression. After a lot of unsuccessful attempts, I tried `[\p{Latin}\d\s]*[^\p{Latin}]+[\p{Latin}\d\s]*` that gives a correct answer to `АО АЛСЕКО`, `Československá obchodní banka`, `11번가(주)`, `11com7 design` and `(주)인포바인`, but not with `АО "Altyn Bank"`, `АКБ "Kapitalbank` or `iBankマーケティング株式会社`

What I might be doing wrong?

Comment: First, make sure you understand your requirements. It is not at all clear what the criteria for filtering are.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Try `=REGEXMATCH(A1,".*([\x{0080}-\x{02AF}]|\d.*[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z].*\d).*|^[a-zA-Z]+$")`, it will output `TRUE` where you have `#N/A` expected. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VoZJce/2).

Comment: Hello, is Wiktor's comment useful to you?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1,".*([\x{0080}-\x{02AF}]|\d.*[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z].*\d).*|^[a-zA-Z]+$")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VoZJce/2)

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `([\x{0080}-\x{02AF}]|\d.*[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z].*\d)` -

  - `[\x{0080}-\x{02AF}]` - a character from `U+0080` to `U+02AF` range
  - `|` - or
  - `\d.*[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z].*\d` - a digit, any 0+ chars as many as possible, ASCII letter, or an ASCII letter, then 0 or more chars as a digit after
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible

  - `|` - or
- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string